# Using IPMI inside a python script (OpenIPMI)

Tags: python, boot

I'd like to use IPMI to set a machine to PXE boot (i.e. `ipmitool -I lan -U username -P password -H ipaddress chassis bootdev pxe`) and then power cycle it (i.e. `ipmitool -I lan -U username -P password -H ipaddress chassis power cycle`).  However, I'd like to do this in a python script so I'm trying to use OpenIPMI and its python bindings.

I can't seem to find any documentation on OpenIPMI for a python script and I'm not sure how to correctly apply IPMI commands (making sure the machine is in the right state so the commands don't fail).  Can someone please show me some pointers or resources on using OpenIPMI (or an alternative) to operate IPMI commands in python?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something so simple it is much easier to just run those commands using the [**subprocess** module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

However, if you still choose the **openimpi** module here is an example of how to use it:
http://www.mail-archive.com/ipmitool-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01445.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the document [IPMI – A Gentle Introduction with OpenIPMI](http://openipmi.sourceforge.net/IPMI.pdf) very helpful. It gives good understanding where/how to get the information. As I understood Python can talk to "shared Library" over using Swig. I hope it will help you.